# Reversing a string - local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python

```
def reverse(text):

    for i in range(1, len(text) + 1):
       a += text[len(text) - i]
    return a

print(reverse("Hello World!"))

#error local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: You do understand what `+=` does, right?

Comment: Spoiler: [How to reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Comment: The issue is, you didn't initialize the variable `a`. Set `a = 0` after `def reverse(text):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a += text[len(text) - i]
```

is equivalent to

```
a = a + text[len(text) - i]
#   ^ 
#   |
#   +-- what's a here?
```

and when this line first runs it has to look up the value of `a` where I've pointed but it can't because `a` has never been assigned before.

Put `a = ''` at the very beginning of your function so that it has a starting value to work from.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute like this:

```
def reverse(text):

    a = ''
    for i in range(1, len(text) + 1):
       a += text[len(text) - i]
    return a


print(reverse("Hello World!"))
```

Output:

```
!dlroW olleH
```

Explanation:

Define the `a` which you are updating in `for-loop` as `a = ''`